# Transposing x and y axes with matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use a bar chart to visualize my csv data. The data looks like this:

```
question,count_1,count_2,count_3,count_4,count_5
Q1,0,0,6,0,0
Q2,6,0,0,0,0
Q3,3,2,1,0,0
Q4,0,0,6,0,0
Q5,6,0,0,0,0
Q6,0,6,0,0,0
Q7,6,0,0,0,0
Q8,0,0,0,5,1
Q9,1,4,0,0,1
Q10,0,0,1,5,0
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
ax = df.set_index(['question']).plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Which gives me:

[image: plot]

What I'm trying to do is flip the x and y axes. I want the bars to be horizontal and y axis to be the questions. I tried to transpose my data frame using:

```
ax = df.set_index(['question']).T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

but that gives me:

[image: plot_2]

which is not what I want. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the bars horizontally (flip the x and y axis), you need to use barh (horizontal bar). More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html). So, the code would be...

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
ax = df.set_index(['question']).plot.barh(stacked=True)
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]